# Array to string conversion PHP ERROR

Tags: php, sql, arrays

In my database SQL, I have messages flowing between user a and b. I want to echo out all the messages they have had. But I am getting the error "array to string conversion" at the moment. I tried to use `implode` but that didn't work too well. How can I receive every row of messages flowing between both users?

```
$query = "SELECT message "
       . "FROM chat "
       . "WHERE (user_name='a' or user_name='b') "
       . "AND (user_to='b' or user_to='a')";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$retrievedata = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo $retrievedata;
```

Comment: Just do: print_r($retrievedata);

Comment: The result of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (if you read the PHP documentation) is an associative array.... you can't echo an array, only array elements, like `echo $retrievedata['message'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) fetches a single row, as an associative array (column name to value). In order to print all the messages, you'd have to go over the entire result set:

```
while ($retrievedata = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $retrievedata['message'];
}
```

Mandatory comment:
`mysql*` has been deprecated for several years now. Please use [`mysqli*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Sidenote: I'm really quite intrigued as to the "mandatory" commenting I've seen a few times regarding the use of APIs; something I've yet to have found related to this topic and how does Stack "force" us or make it "mandatory" to mention the use of `mysqli_` or PDO. Both of which I might add won't safeguard against injection unless using prepared statements along with XSS related functions. If we don't mention, do we get penalized for it? If so, why? Doesn't make any sense really, probably a few extremists who will DV us if we don't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there's a notion that StackOverflow shouldn't encourage the usage of deprecated APIs, so, at the very least, answers about `mysql` should comment that there are better alternatives out there. I can't say I'm 100% convinced, but I understand where this sentiment comes from, and when in Rome...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Additionally, there's no danger of SQL injection here - it's a hard coded query, with no user input.

Comment: Yes I agree, we shouldn't encourage the use of `mysql_` functions. I just find it a bit harsh on some of the persons who at times downvote an answer simply because we haven't made a mention about certain APIs and their potential vulnerabilities; a pity really. We shouldn't be "penalized" for it though. I haven't found anything on meta about this, but am sure if I dig a little deeper, I will. And when in Rome, I will surely drop in for "un caffè macchiato", *cheers/ciao*

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump($retrievedata)` to print values of an array

Comment: `print_r` and `var_dump` are most suitable for debug purposes, I would prefer @Mureinik answer